# ScalaCheck generates StackOverflowError

Tags: scala, scalacheck

I want to create generators (for ScalaCheck) to generate propositional formula. If I create a generator to generate formulas with the variable and and-logic operator (example: A and B) all is right. But if i add or, implies and not, ScalaCheck generates  `Exception: java.lang.StackOverflowError`.

```
import org.scalacheck.Prop
import org.scalacheck.Properties
import org.scalacheck.Gen

object FormulaWffSpecification extends Properties("FormulaWff") {

  abstract class FormulaWff {
    def size: Int
    def depths: Int
  }
  case class And(left: FormulaWff, right: FormulaWff)     extends FormulaWff
  case class Or(left: FormulaWff, right: FormulaWff)      extends FormulaWff
  case class Implies(left: FormulaWff, right: FormulaWff) extends FormulaWff
  case class Not(son: FormulaWff)                         extends FormulaWff
  case class Var(string: String)                          extends FormulaWff

  val genAnd = for {
    left  <- myGenFormula
    right <- myGenFormula
  } yield And(left, right)

  val genOr = for {
    left  <- myGenFormula
    right <- myGenFormula
  } yield Or(left, right)

  val genImplies = for {
    left  <- myGenFormula
    right <- myGenFormula
  } yield Implies(left, right)

  val genNot = for {
    son <- myGenFormula
  } yield Not(son)

  val genVar = Gen.oneOf(Var("A"),Var("B"))

  def myGenFormula: Gen[FormulaWff] =
    Gen.lzy(Gen.oneOf(genVar, genAnd, genImplies, genOr, genNot))

  property("size(t) <= 2^(depths(t) + 1) - 1") = {
    Prop.forAll(myGenFormula) { f: FormulaWff =>
      f.size <= Math.pow(2, f.depths + 1) - 1
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The obvious intuition is that the definition for `myGenFormula` is recursive.  That would be the explanation for the stack overflow.

One part of solving it is making sure to add `Gen.lzy` in the correct places for `myGenFormula`.  This makes sure to execute a single path of generators and avoids needlessly executing all of the recursive generators.

There is a secondary issue with the definition for `myGenFormula` that will cause a stack overflow.  As written, the definition for `myGenFormula` is statistically unlikely to terminate.  The `genVar` generator is the terminating generator, but it is equally weighted with the other non-terminating generators.  There is nothing to keep ScalaCheck from generating an infinite depth of data structures before reaching a stack overflow.

There are two ways to help recursive generators terminate in ScalaCheck.  You can pass a numeric depth argument with `Gen.sized` to your generators, or you could use `Gen.frequency`.

There is also an initialization issue with the mutually recursive generators.  You need to use the `lazy` keyword on the generator `val`s that reference `myGenFormula` to avoid that.

Here's a solution that sprinkles `lazy`, `Gen.lzy` and `Gen.frequency` in your code so that it runs and terminates.  You will probably need to tune to your testing needs.

```
lazy val genAnd = for {
  left <- myGenFormula
  right <- myGenFormula
} yield And(left, right)

lazy val genOr = for {
  left <- myGenFormula
  right <- myGenFormula
} yield Or(left, right)

lazy val genImplies = for {
  left <- myGenFormula
  right <- myGenFormula
} yield Implies(left, right)

lazy val genNot = for {
  son <- myGenFormula
} yield Not(son)

val genVar =
  Gen.oneOf(Var("A"), Var("B"))

val myGenFormula: Gen[FormulaWff] =
  Gen.frequency(
    4 -> genVar,
    1 -> Gen.lzy(genAnd),
    1 -> Gen.lzy(genImplies),
    1 -> Gen.lzy(genOr),
    1 -> Gen.lzy(genNot))

property("myGenFormula") = {
  Prop.forAll(myGenFormula) { f: FormulaWff =>
    true
  }
}
```

Comment: This answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54947773/5826349) addresses a similar issue

Comment: Yes, binary trees pose similar issues, but a grammar like this has a few other difficult hurdles.